# How to interact with a network without a wallet installed?

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3-providers

I'm making a Dapp for users who don't have a wallet installed and have no ETH address. I would like users to use my account for all transactions.

I'd like to sign my transactions with the contract owner address using his private key.

But I can't find a way to doing that.
Please gimme some help

I'm using web3@1.0 (web3.js)
For the moment, my contract is deployed throw the Ropsten Testnet

Comment: Your title and description seems to be conflicting. Do you want to develop a DApp without a wallet like MetaMask installed in browser. Is that correct?

Comment: Hum, I have an ETH account because I'm the contract creator, but the future users won't have ones.

Comment: You need an ETH account to interact with Ethereum, so I'm not sure how your future users would use your DApp

Comment: Ok, like they don't have accounts, my aim is to make transactions with my account and so to pay fees for them, do you understand?
It's for a little company, not a public market

Answer (score 2):

You have to use sendRawTransaction method for all messages. That require you to sign every message with senders private key (in your case contract owners) and does not depend on any installed wallets. You could use [web3js-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw) to make this process easy and sample using this can be found [here](https://github.com/fidenz-chim/fundsplitter_web3jsraw.git).

Comment: I try and feedback ty :)